# Panda3D and load_model c++

Tags: c++, panda3d

I am new to panda3d and am trying the hello world.

I have gotten the program to run with just:

```
PandaFramework framework;
framework.open_framework(argc, argv);
WindowFramework *window = framework.open_window();

framework.main_loop();
framework.close_framework();
return 0;
```

however, if I add in :

```
NodePath environt = window->load_model(framework.get_models(), "panda-model");
environt.reparent_to(window->get_render());
environt.set_scale(0.25, 0.25, 0.25);
environt.set_pos(-8, 42, 0);
```

before the main_loop(), it won't compile. I have the panda-model.egg.pz in every folder of my c++ project but every time my program breaks on :

```
environt.reparent_to(window->get_render());
```

The excat message is: Unhandled exception at 0x0152a317 in Irr.exe: 0xC00001A5: An invalid exception handler routine has been detected.

It compiles fine the only wraning being that it can't find the pdb files but that doesn't matter.

Any ideas?

Btw, im using MSVC++ 2010 and panda3d 1.7.2

The only error I can find is : First-chance exception at 0x00bfa317 in Irr.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x737265db.
Unhandled exception at 0x00bfa317 in Irr.exe: 0xC00001A5: An invalid exception handler routine has been detected.
The program '[8476] Irr.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

which I'm pretty sure is still rather vague. I'm sorry but its all I can find. I'd be happy to describe it more though if necessary.

Comment: "It wont compile" is kind of... vague. Could you please edit your question to include the actual compilation/linker errors? And the error message you post is not a compilation error, it's a runtime error, also known as a "crash". To catch that you have to run your program in a debugger.

Comment: It compiles every time, it just breaks when I add in the import code.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 is not supported by current versions of Panda3D.  You will need to use 2008 or compile the Panda3D SDK from source against MSVC 2010.  (This is not as straightforward as it sounds, as you will also need to compile some of the thirdparty packages to be compatible with 2010.  However, it is possible.)

If you insist on using 2010 instead of 2008, this forum post may be helpful:
https://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=12663

Comment: This is no longer true as of writing; MSVC 2010 is supported in the CVS version of Panda3D.  See this thread: https://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=16346

Comment: That previous comment is no longer true; Panda3D now requires at least MSVC 2015.